# Unity C# rotate object back and forth between vals

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a turrent on a swivel created in blender that I would like to have rotating back and forth in a preview screen so I got this so far

```c#
public float speed = 1.5f;

private GameObject turrent;

private Quaternion localRotation;

private float maxVal = 140f;
private float minVal = 55f;

private void Start(){
    turrent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
}

private void Update(){
    localRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp (speed, minVal, maxVal);
    turrent.transform.rotation = localRotation;
}
```

I thought this would make it go back and forth between the 2 values but it just snaps to 140 degress in `y` and doesn't go back and forth.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Clamp just makes smaller-than-minimum values to be minimum and larger-than-maximum values be maximum. You'll have to write the logic yourself that makes it go back and forth. In the simplest way add a variable that you add to the angle and when it goes over max or under min negate its value

Comment: Use the Lerp function, if I remember correctly it is also in the Mathf library.

Comment: The accepted answer on the duplicate worked for me!